# How to live monitor the number of users using my azure bot?

Tags: node.js, monitor, azure-bot-service

I have created a bot using azure services i wanted to monitor my active session and number of users to provide a better experience for the user.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how granular (and how live) you want to go. Application insights is where you want to look. If you set your bot up with AppInsights, you will get the Analytics blade on your bot. This, at the very least, will show you # users, channels being used and retention of users.

If you want more than that, I would ensure your app service code (bot) is setup to use AppInsights as well. Please find more information [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-telemetry-analytics-queries?view=azure-bot-service-4.0).

Comment: Thank you, for the answer. I have deployed my bot in msteams. I have many users using my bot but still appInsight shows only one user.

Comment: Did you create your bot from a visx or azure template, or one of the samples?

Comment: The location where you only see one user; is that in the Analytics blade?